# Pourquoi public mais tragique, pratique, physique etc. ?

Tags: orthographe

La plupart des adjectifs se terminant par \ik\ s'écrivent **ique** au masculin comme au féminin, mais pas *public* qui différencie masculin (**-ic**) et féminin (**-ique**).

Le [cnrtl](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/public) note à propos de l'adjectif *public* :

> La forme masc. public est tirée de publique en usage, pour les 2 genres, jusqu'au xviies.

Ma question est : sait-on pourquoi l'orthographe de public est irrégulière comparée aux autre adjectifs en \ik\ ?

Comment: C'est plus chique avec un -c ;-)

Comment: @LétaleD'incivilisation _publicque_ est attesté dans la page du CNRTL.

Comment: @Amessihel Merci, [en effet](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/public). J'essayais de deviner et je me disais que ça avait un lien avec cette forme, qui me faisait penser à _grecque_, mais c'est absolument sans importance, je ne ne connais pas le sujet, ce qui importe c'est d'avoir une réponse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En français moderne, le suffixe « -icus » donne pour les **adjectifs** la terminaison « -ique » que ce soit au féminin ou au masculin, à l'exception de « public » et « laïc » (encore qu'au masculin on écrit « laïque » aussi).

En moyen français, il existait des adjectifs avec un suffixe -ic au masculin et -icque au féminin. Selon le *Traité de la formation de la langue* (inclus dans le  *Dictionnaire général de la langue française du commencement du XVIIIe siècle jusqu'à nos jours*, publié entre 1890 et 1900) :

> La règle générale de formation du féminin est troublée soit par des modifications orthographiques, soit par des modifications phonétiques. [...] **Public**, dans le moyen français, form[e] [son] féminin soit en ajoutant que au masculin, soit en supprimant devant cette terminaison le c du masculin : [...] publicque ; [...] publique. [Le féminin actuel publique] nous ramènent à ces deux modes de notation du féminin. ([Source](http://barthes.enssib.fr/translatio/langueXIX/dg/14_t3.htm).)

Il semble que seul « public » ait survécu d'une liste de 1577 d'adjectifs d'après un [article](https://www.ledevoir.com/opinion/idees/488559/linguistique-sexes-genres-et-evolution-en-francais) de Céline Labrosse, linguiste-chercheure, dans le journal Le Devoir.

---

**(Mise à jour.)** En supplément, un article très intéressant : *[Public (histoire du mot)](http://publictionnaire.huma-num.fr/notice/public-histoire-du-mot/)*.

Comment: Aussi *caduc / caduque*, *franc / franque*, *turc / turque*, *grec / grecque*, On retrouve cette affinité avec certains substantifs, sans qu'ils aient forcément de liens entre eux : *le basilic / la basilique*, *le lac / la laque*, *un clic /  une clique*, *un clac / une claque*, *un bic / une bique*, *un cric / une crique*, *un pic / une pique*, *le plastic / (le)/la plastique*, *le tic / la tique*, *le marc / la marque*, *un banc / une banque*, *le trac / la traque*.

Comment: @jlliagre, C'est exact, d'ailleurs le dictionnaire cité mentionne grec/grecque/greque. Ma réponse se limite aux _adjectifs se terminant en -ic_.